# Iphone 7 Blocking numbers mysteriously

Tags: software-update, iphone, hacking

I’m having an issue with my iPhone 7 and I believe it’s been compromised. One of the phone numbers in my phone was mysteriously blocked and one happens to be the one phone number that shouldn’t be blocked under any circumstances. I only realized the number was blocked when the person informed me that she wasn’t able to get through to me. I’ve had the phone with me the entire time. Does any one know how that phone number could have become blocked?

Comment: Ist that number being blocked repeatedly and reproducibly, or just once or occasionally?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to check before you can make sure numbers are automatically blocking on your device.

- Go to **Settings  > Phone > Call Blocking and Identification** and
  check if you find the same number which you think is blocked?
- Also at the top you'll see apps that have access to call blocking.
  See if there is any app that is automatically blocking numbers?

[image]

If your answer is NO to both questions then you should check with your phone carrier and see if there is any problem in your phone network.

Comment: I see this still hasn't been resolved.  Getting pretty sick and tired of it.  I can wipe out my block list and a year later it's a mile long list again.  Like a dummy I just spent half a day trying to figure out why we could text our kid but she couldn't text us.  Yup, it bit me again!  She was auto added to the block list.  Once I got one call from a hospital regarding my mothers operation.  I was expecting more calls throughout the operation, nope, blocked!  iOS12, iPhone XS...still happening!  Also, no, no apps are listed for access to block list.

Answer (score 0):

If you share an Apple ID with anyone else (spouse, kids, etc.), you’ll all share the same blocked contacts list. When one of you blocks someone, all of you block them. If one unblocks someone, they’re unblocked for all of you. Don’t know if that’s your issue but it’s been driving us crazy over here until I figured it out.